# RTK Query - query on mount when lazy is used

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Is it okay to invoke rerender by making a request on mount? Or `useEffect` is neeeded? (Maybe lazy mode is different from ordinary query?)

```
export const Catalog: React.FC<CatalogProps> = ({ object, category }) => {
  const [getCatalogProducts, result] = useLazyGetCatalogProductsQuery();
  const { data, isUninitialized } = result;

  const request = `object_like=${object}&category=${category}`;

  if (isUninitialized) {
    getCatalogProducts(request);
  }

  if (!data) return;

  return (
    // some jsx code
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay to invoke rerender by making a request on mount?

Yes, it's ok to do just about anything when the component mounts.

> Or `useEffect` is needed?

Yes, you should use the `useEffect` hook to issue a side-effect when the component mounts.

```
export const Catalog = ({ object, category }: CatalogProps) => {
  const [
    getCatalogProducts,
    { data, isUninitialized }
  ] = useLazyGetCatalogProductsQuery();

  useEffect(() => {
    const request = `object_like=${object}&category=${category}`;

    if (isUninitialized) {
      getCatalogProducts(request);
    }
  }, []); // <-- empty dependency array, run once after initial render cycle

  if (!data) return;

  return (
    // some jsx code
  );
};
```

> Maybe lazy mode is different from ordinary query?

Yes, it certainly is. The main difference is that the regular queries are automatically triggered and the lazy queries are not. Generally you'll use the regular queries since the "lazy" queries are more of an "on-demand" situation, e.g. user clicks a button and you want the query to run. The regular queries will also be initialized when the component mounts.

You can review the [Hooks Overview](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#hooks-overview) to get the complete rundown on differences.

[image]

Comment: And now i know difference between evoke/invoke.